# Picking dates in Jquery and calling methods

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery DatePicker control From and To. Once the date is changed in either of them, I want to call a controller method. How can I do this and how can associate the event of changing date to the function.

Assume that Controller is called TestController and the method is TestMethod and it takes two parameters namely DateTime StartDate and DateTime EndDate.

Any ideas and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: use the onchange event of the textboxes that are recieving the dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the onselect event for jquery datepicker to trigger a call to the controller once user select any date:

```
  $('#date').datepicker({

        // Once date change, call controller action
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            $.ajax({
                 url: '/TestController/TestMethod',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: { startDate: sDate, endDate: eDate},
                 success: function (result) {
                   // Do action you need upon success call
                 }
            });
        }
    });
```

Hope this is what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to have your `TestController` listen for the datepicker's `onClose` event, and have that method call `testMethod`.

Comment: Assuming the date is a textbox bound to the date picker, using the onClose of the datapicker would not handle typing in dates, where the onchange of the textbox would. On that note make sure to filter out the fact that a typed value may not be a valid date value as well.

Comment: True enough. I was just looking at the specific events that datepicker objects provide, and it was the first one that seemed reasonable. `onChange` makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/TestController/TestMethod" method="post">
    <label for="StartDate">from</label>
    <input type="text" name="StartDate" />
    <label for="EndDate">to</label>
    <input type="text" name="EndDate" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[name='StartDate']").datepicker();
    $("input[name='EndDate']").datepicker();
    $("input[name='StartDate'], input[name='EndDate']").change(function() {
        // add additional validation
        $("form").submit();
        // alternatively you may call $.ajax({...});
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E3kHs/2/